# How to properly check if RabbitMQ channel has been opened after reconnection in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using `amqplib` which I'm trying to implement a reconnecting mechanism. However, after the connection is reestablished it looks like my channel is still closed. How do I fix this issue? This is my code.

```
var pubQueue = [];
module.exports = {
  connect: function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    amqp.connect(config.queue.url, function(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("[AMQP]", err.message);
        return setTimeout(module.exports.connect, 2000);
      }

      connection.on("error", function(err) {
        if (err.message !== "Connection closing") {
          console.error("[AMQP] conn error", err.message);
        }
      });

      connection.on("close", function() {
        console.error("[AMQP] reconnecting");
        return setTimeout(module.exports.connect, 2000);
      });

      connection.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
        console.log('connection is reestablished');
        self.channel = ch;
        return callback ? callback() : false;
      });
    });
  },

  publish: function (message, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var key = this.generateKey(message);
    var m = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(message));

    try {
      self.channel.assertExchange(config.queue.exchange, 'topic', {durable: false, nowait: true});
      self.channel.publish(config.queue.exchange, key, m, {nowait: true});
      return callback ? callback() : true;
    } catch(err) {
      pubQueue.push({key: key, m: m});
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

`connect()` will be called once the express application is started. But `publish` will be call on every request. That's why I have `pubQueue` to store the missing messages. I haven't implemented the function to resend the messaged in the queue but I got this error first which I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```
connection is reestablished
{ [IllegalOperationError: Channel closed]
  message: 'Channel closed',
  stack: 'IllegalOperationError: Channel closed\n    at Channel.}
```

Comment: fwiw, there is a library called wascally, built on top of amqplib, that has this feature built into it: https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/wascally

Answer (score 0):

When the connection closes, set `self.channel` to null and in `publish()`, if self.channel is null, return without doing anything (there are probably better ways but this demonstrates the capability).

By the way, since `connect` needs a callback argument, wrap `setTimeout` in a `Promise` and use `then()` to call your connect function with the callback argument, like this:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
}).then(() => {
  module.exports.connect(callback);
});
```

So the revised code, when starting up with no RabbitMQ running, repeatedly attempts connecting until RabbitMQ has started. It begins publishing repeatedly and if RabbitMQ stops, it gracefully attempts to reconnect and also ceases publishing.

The working code consists of a server used I used for testing, `s.js` , that connects and then repeatedly calls publish:

```
const amqp = require("./so.js");

const doPublish = () => {
  amqp.publish("test", () => {
    console.log("publish complete");
  });
  // publish again
  setTimeout(doPublish, 2000);
};

amqp.connect(function () {
  doPublish();
})
```

The revised version of your code, `so.js`, follows:

```
var config = {
  queue: {
    url: "amqp://localhost/",
    exchange: 'so_exchange',
  },
};

var amqp = require("amqplib/callback_api");

var pubQueue = [];

module.exports = {

  reconnect: function (callback) {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
    }).then(() => {
      module.exports.connect(callback);
    });
  },

  connect: function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    amqp.connect(config.queue.url, function (err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("[AMQP]", err.message);
        return module.exports.reconnect(callback);
      }

      connection.on("error", function (err) {
        if (err.message !== "Connection closing") {
          console.error("[AMQP] conn error", err.message);
        }
      });

      connection.on("close", function () {
        console.error("[AMQP] reconnecting");
        self.channel = null;
        return module.exports.reconnect(callback);
      });

      connection.createChannel(function (err, ch) {
        console.log("connection is reestablished");
        self.channel = ch;
        return callback();
      });
    });
  },

  publish: function (message, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var key = 'test'; //this.generateKey(message);
    var m = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message));

    if (self.channel == null) return;

    try {
      self.channel.assertExchange(config.queue.exchange, "topic", {
        durable: false,
        nowait: true,
      });
      self.channel.publish(config.queue.exchange, key, m, { nowait: true });
      return callback();
    } catch (err) {
      pubQueue.push({ key: key, m: m });
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```